# Created a nested entities using jhipster, but getting db table creation error during application startup

Tags: mysql, spring, liquibase, jhipster

I have created a nested entities below in the following order using jhipster successfully but on application startup I'm getting db table generation errors. Not sure if the error makes sense as it is too long to post here. I'll try to regenerate again and see if the same error occurs and will comment for the same. Thanks.

```
[divison] 1..* [region] 1..* [area] 1..* [site]

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.mycompany.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1e619ac' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1e619ac': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
......
2016-01-08 22:43:57.530  WARN 684 --- [del1-Executor-1] liquibase                                : Failed to restore the auto commit to true
2016-01-08 22:43:57.532 ERROR 684 --- [del1-Executor-1] c.m.m.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:363) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.close(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1176) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:400) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$23(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1235) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1230) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4833) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy.setAutoCommit(ConnectionProxy.java:334) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.HikariConnectionProxy.setAutoCommit(HikariConnectionProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-2.4.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:361) ~[liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted

HIKARI LOG
: Configuring Datasource
: HikariPool-1 - configuration:
: allowPoolSuspension.............false
: autoCommit......................true
: catalog.........................
: connectionInitSql...............
: connectionTestQuery.............
: connectionTimeout...............30000
: dataSource......................
: dataSourceClassName.............com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
: dataSourceJNDI..................
: dataSourceProperties............{user=model3, url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/model3?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, password=<masked>, prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048, cachePrepStmts=true, maximumPoolSize=50, prepStmtCacheSize=250}
: driverClassName.................
: healthCheckProperties...........{}
: healthCheckRegistry.............
: idleTimeout.....................600000
: initializationFailFast..........true
: isolateInternalQueries..........false
: jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
: jdbcUrl.........................
: leakDetectionThreshold..........0
: maxLifetime.....................1800000
: maximumPoolSize.................10
: metricRegistry..................com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry@109fdeb
: metricsTrackerFactory...........
: minimumIdle.....................10
: password........................<masked>
: poolName........................HikariPool-1
: readOnly........................false
: registerMbeans..................false
: scheduledExecutorService........
: threadFactory...................
: transactionIsolation............
: username........................
: validationTimeout...............5000
: HikariPool-1 - is starting.
: Property maximumPoolSize does not exist on target class com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setMaximumPoolSize; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setMaximumPoolSize
```

Comment: Which version of JHipster? Did you sucessfully start your app before creating your own entities?

Comment: I am using "generator-jhipster": "2.26.2". I have successfully run and tested the application before creating new entities.

Comment: Try increasing log level of connection pool (com.zaxxer.hikari) maybe you'll get more details about why connection is closed. It could be also that an operation takes too long (check log timestamps)  and your MySQL server aborts it. You could also try tuning your datasource by increasing spring.datasource.maxActive in application.yml.

Comment: I re-created my entities (10 total) with the same nested entity definition. I increased the log level of Hikari Pool. The default pool size was 10, was there any configuration to set this property? I have manually set this pool size on the DatabaseConfiguration and  I have also tried to set spring.datasource.maxActive and still getting same errors.    I did not see reading this property in the DatabaseConfiguration.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to find something in mysql logs? Can you share a git repo?

Comment: I did not see anything strange on the mysql logs. The max connections allowed is 100. I have added the debug gathered from hikari on my orginal post.

Comment: Due to this error "Property maximumPoolSize does not exist on target class com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" your datasource init failed, how did you define your datasource in application-dev.yml? Could you share your code on github?